# dplyr: passing column name to summarize inside function

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following example, where I pass a simple dataframe to a function that summarizes a column. The name of the summarizing column, `s`, I would like to have as a parameter to the function:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                 a=c(1:10),
                 b=c(10:19))

sum <- function(df, s){
  df <- df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarize(s = sum(a))
  return(df)
}

sum(df = df, s = "summarizing.column.label")
```

However, regardless of the value I set, the summarizing-column always get  the same name `s`. Is there a way to alter it?

---

EDIT: The output I would like is:

```
sum(df = df, s = "summarizing.column.label")

         id     summarizing.column.label
      <dbl> <int>
    1  1.00    15
    2  2.00    40

sum(df = df, s = "a")

         id     a
      <dbl> <int>
    1  1.00    15
    2  2.00    40
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we are passing a quoted argument, then one option is after the `summarise`, we use `rename_at`

```
sumf <- function(df, s){

df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarize(a = sum(a))%>%
     rename_at("a", ~ s) 


 }

sumf(df, s  ="summarizing.column.label" )
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     id summarizing.column.label
#  <dbl>                    <int>
#1  1.00                       15
#2  2.00                       40

sumf(df, s  ="a" )
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     id     a
#   <dbl> <int>
#1  1.00    15
#2  2.00    40
```

---

Or another option is to make use of `:=` with `!!`

```
sumf <- function(df, s){

  df %>% 
     group_by(id) %>%
     summarize(a = sum(a))%>%
     rename(!! (s) := a)
}

sumf(df, s  ="summarizing.column.label" )
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     id summarizing.column.label
#  <dbl>                    <int>
#1  1.00                       15
#2  2.00                       40
```

Or within `summarise`

```
sumf <- function(df, s){

 df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(!!(s) :=  sum(a))
}
```

sumf(df, s  ="summarizing.column.label" )

Comment: I always want to summarize the column `a`. However, the *name* of the column containing the summarized variable I want to change in the OP

Comment: @N08  If you check your original code, it was `s="a"`

Comment: I edited it to make it more clear that it's the label of the summarizing column I want to change, not which variable is being summarized which I believe is what your post is showing (thanks for the swift reply)

Comment: @N08 Are you saying that you are no longer interested in the `summarise` 's' argument?

Comment: I think we are confusing each other. I updated the OP with two examples

Comment: @N08  Updated my post

Comment: @N08 Actually, you can use it within in `summarise`, updated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sum <- function(df, s){
  df <- df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarize(!!s := sum(a))
  return(df)
}
```